# Cant find setup() on userEvent

Tags: react-testing-library, user-event

I am trying to use the user-event utility in testing library as described here :

https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro

Unfortunatley when I try and call the setup function

```
userEvent.setup()
```

My IDE says that it cannot be found :

[image]

Why is this happening?

My import in my file looks like this :

```
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
```

And my package dependencies look like this :

```
"@testing-library/dom": "^8.11.3",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.7.0",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
"@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.2",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `userEvent.setup()` API is added in [v14.0.0](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/releases/tag/v14.0.0)

There is a note in the doc [user-event/intro](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro/)

> These docs describe user-event@14.

Answer (score 1):

First, **updated the version of the User Event package** (as per React recommendation, you can check from their official website as well https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro/)

```
npm install user-event@14
```

**Package.json**

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2"
```

**App.jsx**

```
 import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState<string>("Hello World");
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setName("Hi World")}>Change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.test.jsx**

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import App from "./App";

test("Testing User Event", async () => {
  userEvent.setup();
  render(<App />);
  let btn = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Change" });
  await userEvent.click(btn);
  expect(
    screen.getByRole("heading", { name: /Hi world/i })
  ).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```